# failed to make keyframes animations

Tags: html, css, flexbox, slider, css-animations

I tried to make a slider with images by css keyframes but it doesn't work with me , here is the code :

```
*{
  margin:0;
padding:0;
}

li {
   font-size: 20px;
margin: 10px;
  display : inline-block; } 

a {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;   }

a:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

li:hover {
    transform: scale(1.02);    }

ul li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white ;
         }


.slider {
    min-height: 50vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 90vh;
    background: url(../images/8.jpg);
    animation: 50s slider infinte;   }
  

  @keyframes slider {
      0% {background: url(../images/2.jpg);}
      25% { background: url(../images/3.jpg);}
     50% {background: url(../images/4.jpg);}
     65% { background: url(../images/5.jpg);}
     85% {background: url(../images/6.jpg);}
   100% {background: url(../images/7.png);}
  }
```

note that : slider it's a class integred in div tag who is empty after the navbar .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "background-image" property instead of just "background"?

Answer (score 0):

You slider's default background is `../images/8.png` but you give it  `0% {background: url(../images/2.jpg);}`. Thats might be a problem. I think default value should be same with 0% keyframe

```
    .slider {
        min-height: 50vh;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 90vh;
        background: url(../images/8.jpg);
        animation: 50s slider infinte;   }
      
    
      @keyframes slider {
          0% {background: url(../images/8.jpg);}
          25% { background: url(../images/3.jpg);}
         50% {background: url(../images/4.jpg);}
         65% { background: url(../images/5.jpg);}
         85% {background: url(../images/6.jpg);}
       100% {background: url(../images/7.png);}
      }
```